# How would I pass a value to another page without using 'OnPost'? - ASP. NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am currently trying to pass a value from the variable `username` from my home page to other pages. From my knowledge, I cannot use a form, and so an `OnPost` `IActionResult`, because I have two buttons that lead to different pages, but should both pass the same value of username.

This is on a `.cshtml` and a `.cshtml.cs` page. My program is on ASP.NET 6.0 Core Web App.

I am a student with basic knowledge on ASP.NET Core, and on how to solve this issue, therefore as much of a simplified explanation would be very appreciated.

Here is the code for the `.cshtml` page

```
@page
@model AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Pages.Home_LoggedInModel
@{

}

<div id="main-block" class="text-center">
            <h2>Hey @Model.Username!</h2>
            <h5 class="m-5">
                Please Select Your What Feature to Use Below
            </h5>
            <a class="btn btn-primary mt-1 btn-lg m-5" asp-area="" asp-page="/QuestionSolver/QuestionSolver">Question Solver</a>
            @*I would like to pass the variable 'Username' using these anchor tags *@
            <a class="btn btn-primary mt-1 btn-lg m-5" asp-area="" asp-page="/RevisionQuestions/RevisionQuestions">Revsion Questions</a>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
            <h2>Revision Question Stats:</h2>

            <h5 class="mt-5 mb-5">Total Correct Answers: @Model.CorrectAnsw</h5>
            <h5 class="mt-5 mb-5">Total Answered: @Model.TotalAnsw</h5>
            
</div>
```

Here is the corresponding .cshtml.cs page

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Models;
using AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Data;

namespace AQA_A_Level_CS_NEA__Suvat_Solver_.Pages
{
    [BindProperties(SupportsGet = true)]
    public class Home_LoggedInModel : PageModel
    {
        public String Username { get; set; }
        //Username will already be assigned by passing a value using a form from a previous page
        public int CorrectAnsw { get; set; }
        public int TotalAnsw { get; set; }

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public Home_LoggedInModel(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        public void OnGet()
        {
            User User = new User();
            var CorrectUser = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == Username);
            CorrectAnsw = CorrectUser.UserCorrectAnsw;
            TotalAnsw = CorrectUser.UserTotalAnsw;
        }

    }
}
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: you'd just add it as a query parameter.... for asp.net you can use: asp-route-Username="
@Model.Username"  Ex: <a class="btn btn-primary mt-1 btn-lg m-5" asp-area="" asp-route-Username="@Model.Username" asp-page="/RevisionQuestions/RevisionQuestions">Revsion Questions</a>  (btw you can send this in POST or GET, but for POST you'd add a hidden field)

Comment: @pcalkins Brilliant, this appears to have worked, thank you. Just out of curiosity, how would I send this using a Get method?

Comment: you just did... so the url would be: https: // your_awesome_site/QuestionSolver/QuestionSolver?Username=your_awesome_username  (GET's use name/value pairs in the URL)

Comment: Ah I see, that now makes sense. Many thanks for all of your help!